# javascript code in url if not using $(document).ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net

If I don't wrap my javascript in $(document).ready, any page that the javascript file is included in will cause a http 400 response (bad request). The url has the javascript code appended to the end for some reason... I am using asp.net mvc. Any ideas?

This causes the error:

```
var location = function (vm, data) {}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that's causing this?  Otherwise we can mostly just guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Javascript from the URLs -- it invites cross-site scripting.